# Why i need to add my ipaddress to access the whmcs rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, whmcs

i am new to WHMCS API and i just want call WHMCS API from my spring boot rest template and i am tired of adding my ip address to WHMCS->General Setting->Security->API IP Access Restriction.

Comment: Believe me, it is something good for you, from security point of view. If you want to expose your WHMCS API to any IP, just create a proxy service with single purpose :
-Get the request
-Post to WHMCS API
-Get WHMCS API response
-Return to API client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WHMCS docs, it is a requirement:

> API IP Access Restriction
>
> Advanced. If using the WHMCS API from an off-server location, you must
>   specify the IP address here, otherwise access will be denied.

You can submit a [feature request](https://requests.whmcs.com/) with your concerns so that they may consider an alternative in the future.

Edit:

According to [WHMCS developer documentation](https://developers.whmcs.com/api/access-control/), you can bypass IP Address restriction by using api access key in the `configuration.php` file:

```
$api_access_key = 'secret_key_passphrase_goes_here';
```

then access api with the following URL:

```
whmc-url.com/includes/api.php?action=xxxx&username=xxx&password=xxx&accesskey=secret_key_passphrase_goes_here
```